# Is there a way to increase font size of POS printer using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, opos

How to increase text/font size while printing? I am using EPSON TM-T82 thermal printer.

- OPOS ADK for .Net
- Microsoft POS for .Net

`m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "\u001b|bC" + "\u001b|4C" + 
      "0012"+ "\n"); //print 0012`

Answer (score 0):

By using this escape sequence, you can print enlarged letters.
It is described on page 30-28 of the UnifiedPOS specification.

- Scale horizontally ESC|#hC
  Prints with the width scaled ‘#’ times the normal size, where ‘#’ is replaced by an ASCII decimal string.
  If the scaled printout would exceed the printable area then the printing results may be unpredictable.
- Scale vertically ESC|#vC
  Prints with the height scaled ‘#’ times the normal size, where ‘#’ is replaced by an ASCII decimal string.
  If the scaled printout would exceed the printable area then the printing results may be unpredictable.

Up to the magnification supported by the printer is the limit, probably it is possible to specify about 8 times.
Please refer to the description document of OPOS ADK for.NET.